# Dropbox Sync API AccessToken

Tags: ios, dropbox

When I used the core API I simply used the code

```
[dbsession updateAccessToken:@"..." accessTokenSecret:@"..." forUserId:@"..."];
```

to access my dropbox account from any copy of the app. But now I found out of this new Sync API that is easier and more flexible, but I didn't find any equivalent for the code displayed above. It now is:

```
DBAccountManager* accountMgr = [[DBAccountManager alloc] initWithAppKey:@"..." secret:@"..."];
[DBAccountManager setSharedManager:accountMgr];

??[DBAccountManager updateAccessToken:@"..." accessTokenSecret:@"..." forUserId:@"..."];??
```

How can I access my account? Where can I insert the AccessToken?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to always login to the same dropbox account regardless of where the app is installed on? and by passing the dropbox login process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your question, it seems that this method on `DBAccountManager` is the one for using your `appKey` and `secret`:

```
- (id)initWithAppKey:(NSString *)key secret:(NSString *)secret
```

From the documentation description, it says this method *"...create[s] a new account manager with your app’s app key and secret. You can register your app or find your key at the apps page."*

After you create an instance of `DBAccountManager` and set it to be the shared manager using `[DBAccountManager setSharedManager:]`, you can login the specific user by calling this method:

```
[[DBAccountManager sharedManager] linkFromController:YOUR_ROOT_CONTROLLER];
```

Here's a description from the [dropbox iOS tutorial](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/start/ios):

> *"To start interacting with the Sync API, you'll need to create a DBAccountManager object. This object lets you link to a Dropbox user's account which is the first step to working with data on their behalf"*
>
> *"...the linking process will switch to the Dropbox mobile app if it's installed. Once the user completes the authorization step, Dropbox will redirect them back to your app using the URL scheme you registered when setting up the SDK. Your app needs to handle those requests to complete the auth flow."*

The final step as mentioned in the tutorial is to handle the redirect. Here's some code to do this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)source annotation:(id)annotation {
    DBAccount *account = [[DBAccountManager sharedManager] handleOpenURL:url];
    if (account) {
        NSLog(@"App linked successfully!");
        return YES;
    }
}
```

The user's account information can now be obtained through `[DBAccountManager sharedManager].linkedAccount` which is a `DBAccount` with properties like `userId` and `accountInfo`.

Here's a [link to the docs](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/docs/ios) for reference. Hope this helps!

## Update

It seems I may have misunderstood your question. I am giving you instructions on how to use the Sync API and didn't quite clarify that there is actually **no** place for a user's `accessToken` in the API. This has been replaced with the web flow that I describe above.

Comment: `appKey`, as its name suggests, is an access token for an application. The method signature in the question, `updateAccessToken:accessTokenSecret:forUserId:` is looking for a _user_ access token. They are not the same.

Comment: You've misinterpreted the question. @Alessandro wants to be able to _programmatically_ setup _his_ account using the Sync API _without_ using web flow authentication.

Comment: If I did misunderstand him, then the answer is that **you cannot use the Sync API with the `accessToken`, if I'm not missing something in the docs.** I thought he was asking how he would switch to the Sync API and was wondering how he could access his account, still thinking that he needed to put the `accessToken` in some Dropbox method.

Comment: @neilco is right, you did misinterpret the question. So as you say in the comment above there is no way to use access token in shnc api....even with unofficial methods

Comment: Alright, I've added the update to my answer for completeness sake.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want by generating a callback url that dropbox uses in the sync API.  First you need to set the `dropbox.sync.nonce` user setting to match whatever you pass in as the state parameter in the NSURL.  Then set the oauth_token, oauth_token_secret, and uid params with what you used to pass into `[DBAccountManager updateAccessToken:@"..." accessTokenSecret:@"..." forUserId:@"..."];`.  See below:

```
  NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  [userDefaults setObject:@"9b0aa24b0bd50ce3a1a904db9d309c50"
                   forKey:@"dropbox.sync.nonce"];
  [userDefaults synchronize];

  NSURL *url =
      [NSURL URLWithString:@"db-APP_KEY://1/connect?
oauth_token=updateAccessToken&
oauth_token_secret=accessTokenSecret&
uid=forUserId&
state=9b0aa24b0bd50ce3a1a904db9d309c50"];    

  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Notice how the state parameter is the same as the value stored in the user defaults.  Keep in mind this is undocumented and may change in a later API version.

Comment: it is still working? i've done same but it gives me error `[ERROR] unable to verify link request`